# Grid en Bootstrap no se coloca de lado a lado

Tags: html, css, laravel, bootstrap

Tengo un problema en cuanto a este código HTML, estoy usando Laravel y Bootstrap

Por alguna razón, los productos no salen de lado a lado, salen uno debajo del otro y no puedo encontrar el porque, parece que algo anda mal con los div caption y thumbnail pero no puedo solucionarlo correctamente. El resto funciona perfecto menos el grid que debe salir de lado a lado, me gustaría saber como arreglarlo

Este es mi codigo de HTML

```
@extends('layouts.master') 

@section('title')
Shopping Cart
@endsection

@section('content')
<br></br>

 @foreach($products->chunk(3) as $productChunk)
 <div class="row"> <!--  Esta es la tabla de los productos en si-->
  @foreach($productChunk as $product)
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 columna">
  <div class="thumbnail">
  <center><img src="{{ $product->imagePath }}" alt="El Señor de los Anillos" class="img-responsive"></center>
  <h3>{{ $product->title }}</h3> 
  <h3>Descripcion</h3>

   <div class="caption">
   <p class="description">{{ $product->description }}</p>
   <div class="text-left price">${{ $product->price }}</div>
   <div class="text-right"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" role="button">Añadir</a></div>
   </div>

  </div>
  </div>
 </div> 
 @endforeach
</div>
@endforeach

@endsection
```

Este es mi codigo del css

```
.thumbnail img{
   max-height: 200px;
}

.thumbnail .caption{
  color: #7F7F7F;
}

.columna{
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;

}

 .price{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  }
```

Aqui estan las dependencias de Laravel y todo lo que usa Bootstrap (layouts.master)

```
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>@yield('title')</title> <!--Obtiene el titulo del archivo PHP el cuel esta-->

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
  integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script defer src="https://friconix.com/cdn/friconix.js"></script>
  <link href="{{ URL::to('src/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
  @yield('styles') <!--Obtiene el css de arriba-->
</head>

<body>
@include('partials.header') <!--Obtiene la barra de navegacion -->

<div class="container">
@yield('content') <!--Coloca lo que se encuentre con la tag contenido en la pagina -->
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
  integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
@yield('scripts') <!--Coloca los scripts de bootstrap -->

</body>

</html>
```

[image: Aqui esta la foto de como luce]

Comment: prueba agregando la clase d-flex al div de las filas `@foreach($products->chunk(3) as $productChunk) <div class="row d-flex"> ...`

Comment: Lo intente y no funciono, sigue igual

Comment: si indentas el código notarás que tienes una etiqueta `</div>` de más dentro del foreach anidado, posiblemente sea eso

Comment: Eso resolvio el problema, gracias